# Changing character encoding of multidimensional array

Tags: php

I have a multidimensional array that looks something like this:

```
ourThing = array(
    'id' => 1,
    'title' => 'foo',
    'data' => array(
        'name' => 'bar',
        'metadata' => array(
            'time' => '2011-02-01 12:00:00'
        )
    )
);
```

Now, because I have to use `json_encode` and `json_decode` on them, I need to store at least the stuff in `data` as UTF-8. Unfortunately, the website uses windows-1252, and that's something I can't change. Because I might want to add even more levels to the array (within data) in the future, I figured I'd change the encoding recursively, like so:

```
function encode_items($arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $n => $v) {
        if (is_array($v))
            encode_items($arr[$n]);
        else
            $arr[$n] = mb_convert_encoding($v, 'Windows-1252', 'UTF-8');
    }
}
```

However, this is not working. If I print $arr[$n] right after encoding it, it comes out right, but the original array doesn't seem to change, because when I later try to print out the values from the array, I get character encoding issues.

tl;dr: I need to change the encoding of the information in `ourThing['data']` from utf-8 to windows-1252.

How can I make it so that the original array is changed?

EDIT: Thanks to a helpful commenter, I now know what I was doing wrong. I forgot to actually return the array after doing the encoding. Here's a working example:

```
ourArray = array(
    'id' => 1,
    'title' => 'foo',
    'data' => array(
        'name' => 'bar',
        'metadata' => array(
            'time' => '2011-02-01 12:00:00'
        )
    )
);

function encode_items($arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $n => $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            $arr[$n] = encode_items($v);
        } else {
            $arr[$n] = mb_convert_encoding($v, 'Windows-1252', 'UTF-8');
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}

$ourArray = encode_items($ourArray);
```

Comment: You're missing a `$` in `foreach ($arr as $n => ___v) {`

Comment: Perhaps returning the array would be a solid move!

Comment: @PaulNorman - Oh wow... I have been working on this for far too long. Yes. I hear actually returning something from your functions helps. If you submit that as an answer, I'll shamefully accept it.

Comment: Can we sum the issue as 'the above function does not affect the original array'? Make it use array _references_ instead by using the **ampersand** sign i.e. `&$arr`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

:-)

```
function encode_items($array)
{
    foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {
        if(is_array($value))
        {
            $array[$key] = encode_items($value);
        }
        else
        {
            $array[$key] = mb_convert_encoding($value, 'Windows-1252', 'UTF-8');
        }
    }

    return $array;
}
```

Or you could pass in the array by reference, but I prefer this.

Answer (score 18):

How about this:

```
function myEncodeFunction(&$item)
{
    $item = mb_convert_encoding($item, 'Windows-1252', 'UTF-8');
}

array_walk_recursive($ourThing, 'myEncodeFunction');
```

Or even turn it into a one-liner:

```
array_walk_recursive($ourThing, function(&$item) { $item = mb_convert_encoding($item, 'Windows-1252', 'UTF-8'); });
```

Comment: This is the correct method indeed. Note that by HTML5 standards, `Windows-1252` and  `ISO-8859-1` can be treated as equal encodings.