# Saving a CSV created by PHP directly in ISO encoding

Tags: php, csv, iso

I am trying to create a CSV file using PHP. I want the ISO-8859-1 encoding.
So far I managed to create the CSV file but it has an UTF-8 encoding.

I was able to make it work with `utf8_decode` thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46118202/csv-from-utf8-to-iso-8859-1) which shows how to convert it from ISO to CSV, but my goal is to:

> Create the file directly in ISO-8859-1 encoding directly.

Here is my code (without decode, ask me if you want it as well):

```
    $columns = array(
        'option1' => 'Option1 title',
        'option2' => 'Option2 title',
        'option3' => 'Option3 title'
    );

    /* Setting default values for the array */

    $default = array(
        'option1' => 'value1',
        'option2' => 'value2',
        'option3' => 'value3'
    );

    /* Creating the CSV file */

    $fp = fopen('/tmp/' . $this->fileName, "w");

    if ($fp) {
        fputcsv($fp, array_values($columns), ";");

        foreach ($legListArray as $row) {
            $data = array();

            foreach ($columns as $key => $_dummy) {

                if (substr($key, 0, 7) == "_field_") {
                    $data[] = $row[$key];
                } else {
                    $data[] = $default[$key];
                }
            }

            fputcsv($fp, $data, ";");
        }

        fclose($fp);
    }
```

Comment: Well, the only thing in your code that determines the encoding of the file is whatever you have inside `$legListArray` :-?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just [map the array](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) using [`utf8_decode`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) when calling `fputcsv`.

You only have two lines which are affected:

```
fputcsv($fp, array_map('utf8_decode', array_values($columns)), ";");
...
    fputcsv($fp, array_map('utf8_decode', $data), ";");
```

Or you can do `utf8_decode` when building the array, i.e.:

```
$data[] = utf8_decode($row[$key]);
...
$data[] = utf8_decode($default[$key]);
```